# How to log User.Identity.Name and Request.Url.PathAndQuery down in my data repository?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, logging, repository, httprequest

I am writing an MVC 4 app, based on the default template from VS.
I have my database repository located in the Models folder.
I would like to **do some logging when the users are modifying the db.**

**I would like to place the methods doing the logging down in the repository.
In that way the controller and actions methods don't have to be concerned with the logging.**

As part of the logging I would like to capture:

**var userIdentityName = User.Identity.Name;**

**var pathAndQuery = Request.Url.PathAndQuery;**

**What is an elegant solution to have this information available down in my db repository in the models folder?**

**So I am asking for an elegant method to get this information down to my repository from my controllers and action methods? By the way I am not using Dependency Injection.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made an ActionFilterAttribute, which took care to catch interesting information from the controller layer. Then I stored that information in Session and accessed it again down in my repository, where I was logging an audit trail to the database.

```
    [Audit]
    public ActionResult Index()
```

.

```
public class AuditAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpRequestBase httpRequestBase = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
        HttpContext httpContext = HttpContext.Current;

        string urlPathAndQuery = httpRequestBase.RawUrl;
        string windowsLogonName = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
        string ipAddress = httpRequestBase.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] ?? httpRequestBase.UserHostAddress;

        httpContext.Session["WindowsLogonName"] = windowsLogonName;
        httpContext.Session["UrlPathAndQuery"] = urlPathAndQuery;
        httpContext.Session["IpAddress"] = ipAddress;

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use DI to inject an `ILogger` into your repository, then use the `HttpContext` in your logger (not your repository) to access the info and do the logging.

Comment: I am not using DI in my app. My initial thought was that I just wanted to have User.Identity.Name & Request.Url.PathAndQuery available in my repository, so I could do the logging from down there, forgetting it as much as possible up in the controllers and action methods.

Comment: DI only takes a few minutes to set up and the benefits are huge. I would strongly recommend it. You should be able to access the HttpContext from anywhere, but I would caution against doing so in the repository, as that feels like a violation of separation of concerns, and would make it difficult, if not impossible to unit test your repository.

Comment: That you for your interest in my problem Jason P, I found another solution, using an ActionFilterAttribute, which I currently think fulfils the needs of my simple application.